# The condition Greater Than (>) cannot work in my jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to check the number of characters in class **span**, then change CSS according to the number.

For example, if length of title is less than 29, the title color should be yellow. If length of title is greater than 29, the title color is blue.

I add the condition `if(x > 29)`, but it cannot work, how can I correct my script ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$(".block .title h2 span").each(function(index) {
   var x=$(this).text().length;

      if(x > 29){
        $(".block .title h2 span").css("color","blue");
        $(".block .title h2").css("padding-top","0px");
                }
      else{
        $(".block .title h2 span").css("color","yellow");
        $(".block .title h2").css("padding-top","18px");
        };

});

});
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: @DylanCristy if length of title is less than 29, the title color should be yellow, but all titles with the color blue right now, in fact some titles' length is less than 29

Comment: This is a basic javascript question, and should be on SO.

Comment: Agreed.  But I answered it anyway. :)

Comment: I was typing up the same thing.  Code is working perfectly fine, just flawed in logic.

Comment: @wjervis ah, ok, thank you for information, I always ask question in SharePoint, I forget SO........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what's happening:

```
// select ALL elements that are .block .title h2 span and loop through them
$(".block .title h2 span").each(function(index) {

   // find the length of the text of THIS PARTICULAR element     
   var x=$(this).text().length;

   // if the length of THIS PARTICULAR element is > 29
      if(x > 29) {

        // change the CSS of ALL elements that match .block .title h2 span      
        $(".block .title h2 span").css("color","blue");
        $(".block .title h2").css("padding-top","0px");
      }
      else {

        // change the CSS of ALL elements that match .block .title h2 span 
        $(".block .title h2 span").css("color","yellow");
        $(".block .title h2").css("padding-top","18px");
      };
});
```

You really want your `if` statement to look like this:

```
if (x > 29) {
    $(this).css("color","blue");
    $(this).closest("h2").css("padding-top","0px");
} else {
    $(this).css("color","yellow");
    $(this).closest("h2").css("padding-top","18px");        
}
```